# JavaScript so funciona si o console estiver aberto no IE

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom dia, sou novo aqui to com um problema bem chato.

Uso uma função para ficar atualizando uma div a cada 5 segundo. Em todos os buscadores funciona normalmente, somente no IE que parou de funcionar.

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

.filaAtual{
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    min-height: 120px;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.filaEstatistica{
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    min-height: 120px;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.estadoAgentes{
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    min-height: 150px;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.chamadas{
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    min-height: 150px;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ramais{
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    min-height: 150px;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.URA{
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    min-height: 150px;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nivelServicoOk{
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 25px;
    background:#eee;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nivelServicoWarning{
    border: 1px solid #cc6600;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 25px;
    background:#ff8040;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nivelServicoDanger{
    border: 1px solid #9f0000;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 3px;
    border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 25px;
    background:#ff0000;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nivelServicoDanger p{
    animation: blinker 1s infinite;
    vertical-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 38px;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes blinker {  
  5% { opacity: 0; }
}

.tabelaDados{
    width: 80%;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
.tabelaDados td:nth-child(1) {background: #fff}
.tabelaDados tr:nth-child(even) {background: #E5F1F9}
.tabelaDados tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF0D9}

.td_titulos{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.td_dados{
    text-align: left; 
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.td_headAgentes{
    text-align: center;
    background: #dbdbdb; 
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 25%;

}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Imagens/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">



    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">



   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery_ATUALIZA.js"></script>


    <script src="js/ajusta_padding.js"></script>


<?php
    include_once 'bars/navbar2.php';
    //include_once 'bars/navbar3.php'
?>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->


    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container" >
       <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-offset-2">
            <div id="refresh" class="row" style="z-index: -2px;">             </div>
        </div>   
    </div>


</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


        function atualiza(){

            console.log("atualizou");
            $('#refresh').load('pegaDashboard.php');
            return true;

        }


        $(function(){
            console.log("Inicou");

            window.setInterval(atualiza, 5000);
            $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
                html: true, 
                content: function() {
                    return $('#popover-content').html();
                }
            });
            atualiza();


        }); 

    </script>
```

Porem, isto funciona, menos no IE, mas si eu abro o console no mesmo, ela começa a ser executada.

Alguém ja teve este problema?

Comment: Coloca o HTML e CSS também. Edita a pergunta e coloca o resto do código, sem ele não da para simular o seu problema

Comment: Realmente, não faço ideia porque não funciona. Ele ate executa a função mas não atualiza a div. E somente atualiza a div si o console estiver aberto. Estranhíssimo.

Comment: Resolvido, tinha include de mais, o resto dos browser conseguem lidar já o IE é nojentinho.